# Implement interface in abstract class for derived classes

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I got this interface:

```
Public Interface IGsm
        Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean
End Interface
```

Now I want all child classes to use IGsm interface, therefore I decided to implement it by abstract class (hope it's good approach):

```
  Public Class MustInherit GsmBase
        Implements IGsm

        Public Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean Implements IGsm.Run
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Function

    End Class
```

**First question:**
What if I put Overridable to my function does it mean that I can define some implementation here in base class same for all derived classes and also ovveride rest implementation in derived classes? Is that correct approach?

```
Public Overridable Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean Implements IGsm.Run
             'Some shared code for all child classes
             '......
End Function
```

so derived classes could do:

```
Public Ovverides Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean Implements IGsm.Run
             MyBase.Run
             'add additional code for this specific child class...
End Function
```

Is that all correct what I just wrote?

**Second question:** If I do not mark Run as Overridable in base class. When inheriting from base class to my derived classes does it mean that my derived classes will just have to use the current implementation of that Run method from base class?

**Third question:** Why I cannot mark Run in base class as MustOverides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Functions, Subs and properties and also Interface implementations are inherited in deriving classes, no matter whether the members are Overridable / Overridden or not.
2. Overridable means that a deriving class can just do nothing, if it is happy with the base implementation. A call to a Function will automatically call the base function. But it can override it, if another implementation is desired. You can then decide to call the base implementation or not, depending whether you want to add functionality or want to replace it completely.
3. Apply `MustInherit` to the class. This enables you to apply `MustOverride`  to members. (This is a bit more complicated than in C#, where you can apply the same keyword `abstract` twice.)

```
Public MustInherit Class GsmBase
    Implements IGsm

    Public MustOverride Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean Implements IGsm.Run
End Class
```

Note that you can combine different approaches. You could have several abstract base classes implementing the interface and also classes implementing the interface directly

```
Interface I

MustInherit Class BaseA Implements I
MustInherit Class BaseB Implements I

Class A1 Inherits BaseA
Class A2 Inherits BaseA
Class A2_1 Inherits A2
Class B1 Inherits BaseB
Class B2 Inherits BaseB
Class C Implements I
Class D Inherits C
Class E Inherits D
```

All objects of type `A1`, `A2`, `A2_1`,`B1`, `B2`, `C`, `D` and `E` are assigment compatible to `I`.

Comment: Summarizing implementing interfaces (assuming all childs would use it) by abstract classes is correct approach right? And now if there is need to make shared code in the interface method that all childs can use but every child to extend it this is good to make method Overridable? Or if there is a need interface has to be implemented directly and only for each of child their own and no shared code means i can mark interface method as MustOveride. Am i understanding that  right what i just wrote and according to right coding approach?

Comment: Implementing interfaces by abstract classes is a valid approach. Yes, make method Overridable is a good idea.
Yes, if the base class cannot provide a meaningful implementation, mark the method as `MustOveride`, i.e. make it abstract. (Note that you can take a hybrid approach: a class can also implement the interface directly, while others derive from the base class) Your thoughts are correct.

Comment: if not all derived classes need interface then interface should be implemented directly by required childs and not abstract? Extra question if you don't mind: Saw some developers making classes/interfaces (Of specific type) what could be the situation to do so? If possible to show on my example?

Comment: An interface is a contract. Implementing an interface means that a class complies with the contract. All deriving classes (children) inherit this compliance. It is not so much a question of whether a class needs it; rather, it is a question of whether a class (seen from outside) is compatible with it.

Comment: The `(Of T)` thing is a type parameter. If the final type of a function/sub parameter, a return type or the type of a property is not yet known at the time of the implementation, you can provide a type parameter that will be resolved later. A good example is `List(Of T)`. You can decide what type of objects you want to store when you are creating the list with `New`: `Dim stringList As New List(Of String)` or `Dim gsmList As New List(Of IGsm)`. The implementer of `List` (Microsoft) does not need to and cannot possibly know the existence of `IGsm`.

Comment: I understand the List approach, it's more like question "How to know i need to use to preapre/create (Of T)" during applciation design. Is there easy answet to that question?

Comment: If a functionality is not dependent on a specific type (like inserting things into a list or retrieving things from a list), You have two possibilities to make it available to a wide variety of types: 1) Use the type `Object` for parameters and return types. Or 2) Use generic types. 1) has the disadvantage of not being type safe. I.e. you could erroneously insert a `String` into a list supposed to contain only `Integer`s. Later you get an error when retrieving the object: `Dim Integer x = 5 * list(i)` oops! Cannot multiply with a string. 2) is type safe.

Comment: would it make sense to mark IGsm as Public Interface IGsm(Of GsmBase) ?

Comment: No, since you want to program against the interface, not against the abstract class. The abstract class is just an implementation detail. I.e. you would declare `Dim gsm As IGsm` not as `Dim gsm As GsmBase`. I don't see a useful application of generics in this Gsm example. See this project for VB examples: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11821/Generics-and-Custom-Collection-Classes-in-NET

Comment: i saw your example but what is the sense to use GenericCollection which inheritc CollectionBase? Because i could just use List(Of Customer)... instead of that am i right?

Comment: You are using `List(Of TypeOfWhatYouWantToStoreInTheList)`. This can be a value type, a class (abstract or not), an interface type.

Comment: That's the point so do not get the point out of this tutorial to create a class which inherits from CollectionBase when we have already List(Of T) which could be used.

Comment: I am not inheriting any collection from collection base. I exposed two possible ways to implement a hypothetical collection (generic versus non-generic). `List(Of T)` is ready to be used. You don't have inherit or implement anything. The point is that `T` is open, i.e. it is not defined yet and you can define it freely when you create a `List(Of T)` object. There is also a non-generic list `ArrayList` when you want to store objects of different non-compatible types.

Comment: 1) I ment out of link you provided. I do not see a sense... 2) And what about interface (Of T) ? What are the situations to use it?

Comment: See: [IList(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). It is implemented by arrays, `List(Of T)` and many other collections. Search for "IList" in the object browser of Visual Studio and then look for derived types of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create an abstract class in your sample, it would look like this.

```
Public Interface IGsm
    Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class GsmBase
    Implements IGsm

    Public MustOverride Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean Implements IGsm.Run

End Class

Public Class Gsm
    Inherits GsmBase

    Public Overrides Function Run(filePath As String) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

Then you can use is as

```
    Dim test As IGsm = New Gsm
    test.Run("test") ' This will call Gsm.Run
```

or

```
    Dim test As GsmBase = New Gsm
    test.Run("test") ' This will call Gsm.Run
```

MustInherit is for class, not method. For method you would use MustOverride.